# discrete logarithm equality for independent groups

Tags: discrete-logarithm

Given two different safe primes $p_1$, $p_2$ we construct the subgroups $G_1$ of prime order $q_1 = \frac{p_1-1}{2}$ and $G_2$ of prime order $q_2 = \frac{p_2-1}{2}$. Let $g_1$ be a generator of $G_1$ and $g_2$ be a generator of $G_2$.
We assume that the discrete logorithm is hard in both groups.

Alice randomly selects some secret value $ s \in \mathbb{Z}_{min\{q_1, q_2\}} $. Alice calculates $ x_1 := g_1^s \in G_1 $ and $ x_2 := g_2^s \in G_2 $ and a cryptographic hash $ H(s) $. 
Alice sends $x_1$, $x_2$ and $H(s)$ to Bob via a secure channel.

Is there some pratical way that Bob can be sure that Alice indeed has sent values $ x_1 = g_1^a $ and $ x_2 = g_2^b $ such that $ a = b $? If not, can Alice provide additional data without revealing $s$ to convince Bob?

This question is somewhat related to "[How can we prove that two discrete logarithms are equal?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15758/how-can-we-prove-that-two-discrete-logarithms-are-equal)". However in our case two generators from two different groups are used instead of two generators from one group.

EDIT: Regarding the comments from poncho and Yehuda Lindell I further clarify what I mean by "discrete logarithm equality for independent groups":

I would like to use the following definition for $dlog_{g}$: 
 $ {dlog}_g(g^e) := $ smallest $ x \mid x \geqslant 0, g^x \equiv g^e \pmod p $

Given $ s_1 = dlog_{g_1}(g_1^s) $ and $ s_2 = dlog_{g_2}(g_2^s) $ 
then $ dlog_{g_1}(g_1^s) \ $ equals $ \ dlog_{g_2}(g_2^s) \ $ iff $ \ s_1 = s_2 $

Comment: Well, there is the generic ZK proof for every NP statement... Are you looking for something practical?

Comment: Yes, definitely looking for a practical solution. Based on your comment I guess that a generic ZK proof is not (yet) considered practial - is that correct?

Comment: may I ask if there is any paper talking about this kind of proof?

Answer (score 7):

Let me assume for simplicity that $q_1 \leq q_2$. You want to prove that the discrete log of $x_1$ in $G_1$ is the same that the discrete log of $x_2$ in $G_2$, and that this discrete logarithm *seen as an integer* is smaller than $q_1$. This suggests that you should rely on a zero-knowledge proof for a relation *over the integers*. The most natural method to do this kind of proofs is to work over a group of unknown order, as, intuitively, if the prover does not know the order of the group he cannot reduce the exponents modulo this order - and the relation should hold over the integers.

So, let $G$ be a group of unknown order where the discrete logarithm is hard (for example, the subgroup of squares of an RSA group). Let com$(\cdot)$ be a perfectly hiding integer commitment scheme over $G$ (e.g. the [Fujisaki Okamoto commitment scheme](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-36178-2_8)). Let $s \le q_1$ be your secret exponent. In addition to $x_1 = g_1^{s} \in G_1$ and $x_2 = g_2^s \in G_2$, the prover sends a commitment com$(s) = c$ over $G$.

Let us take the protocol suggested by professor Lindell as a basis. Consider the following modification of this protocol:

- the answers are not computed modulo $q_1\cdot q_2$, but they are instead computed over the integers. For this not to break the zero-knowledge property, the mask $r$ should be taken, say, 160 bits longer than $s$, so as to statistically mask $e\cdot s$ over the integers.
- The prover proves knowledge of $s$ which is the discrete log of $x_1$ and $x_2$ *and* the value committed in $c$
- The prover additionally proves that the value committed in $c$ is lower than $q_1$. The classical method to do so is as follows: both players compute $c’$ from $c$ and $q_1$, a value that commits to $s’ = q_1 - s$ (the Fujisaki-Okamoto scheme is homomorphic, it is essentially com$(m;r) = g^mh^r$). Observe that $s \leq q_1$ is equivalent to $s’ \geq 0$. moreover, by a classical result of Lagrange, an integer is positive if and only if it can be written as a sum of four squares. Therefore, the prover computes this decomposition of $s’$ into a sum of four squares (via the Rabin-Shallit algorithm), commits to them, and proves that $s’$ is the sum of the squares of these committed values. Such a protocol is known as a range proof and is described in several papers, e.g. [this one](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2003/11_Session10/25_103/28940402.pdf).

Once this protocol is complete, the verifier is convinced that the prover knows an integer $s \leq q_1$ such that $g_1^s = x_1$ and $g_2^s = x_2$. One can refine the protocol to make it more efficient, but I tried to make the answer as intuitive as possible.

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure that the regular DDH sigma protocol should work here as well. In order to make things work, a few changes are needed. Specifically:

1. Prover chooses a random $r\in\mathbb Z_{q_1\cdot q_2}$ and computes $h_1 = g_1^r \mod p_1$ and $h_2 = g_2^r \mod p_2$, and sends $h_1,h_2$ to the verifier.
2. The verifier sends a random challenge $e\in\{0,1\}^t$.
3. The prover replies with $z=r+es \mod q_1\cdot q_2$
4. The verifier checks that $g_1^z = h_1 \cdot x_1^e \mod p_1$ and $g_2^z = h_2 \cdot x_2^e \mod p_2$.

This should all work easily for soundness (but needs to be checked). The only question is zero knowledge since $r$ is not chosen randomly in $\mathbb Z_q$ but in $\mathbb Z_{q_1\cdot q_2}$. In the interest of leaving you some interesting work to do, this should be checked. So, try to prove it and then let us know :-).

Comment: Looks promising :) I'll start with an soundness example and then work my way up.

Comment: How does the protocol show that $0 \le s < q_1, q_2$?

Comment: @poncho There is no need to prove the range of $s$. It will automatically be reduced modulo $q_1,q_2$ by the group operation.

Comment: Lets put it this way; suppose I pick arbitrary values $s_1, s_2$, generate $x_1 = g_1^{s_1}$ and $x_2 = g_2^{s_2}$ and compute $s$ with $s \equiv s_1 \pmod{q_1}$ and $s \equiv s_2 \pmod{q_2}$ (which I can always do, as $q_1, q_2$ are relatively prime).  If $s_1 \ne s_2$, what fails within the above ZKP?

Comment: @poncho I didn't see this as a problem, because I guess we have to define what it means to have the same discrete log in groups of different order. If $s=s_1 \bmod q_1$ and $s=s_2 \bmod q_2$ then the question is whether this means that the discrete log is the same. Specifically, by the above, $g_1^{s_1} = g_1^s \bmod p_1$ and $g_2^{s_2} = g_2^s \bmod p_2$. So they *do have the same discrete log*.

Comment: If you take that definition, then the problem becomes "prove that you know both the discrete log of $g_1$ and the discrete log of $g_2$".  However, that's not what raisyn asked for, he specifically stated that $s \in \mathbb{Z}_{min\{q_1, q_2\}}$.

Comment: I missed the min part in the question. However, note that my interpretation is still a natural one and it's not just knowing both; it guarantees that it's the same dlog, for a certain definition of this problem.

Comment: First I really want to thank both of you for the great input. I didn't expect this one to get that difficult. To clearify: The property I need is: "prove that you know the discrete log of $g_1$ and the discrete log of $g_2$ and that they are equal". Given that this statement holds I'm pretty sure I don't need to care  about $ s \in \mathbb{Z}_{min\{q1, q2\}}$. I'm trying to verify that.

Comment: Unfortunately poncho's  interpretation matches mine. I actually need to care about $ s \in \mathbb{Z}_{min\{q1, q2\}} $. Poncho's construction from the comment "Lets put it this way..." should indeed fail if $ s1 \not= s_2 $.

Comment: @YehudaLindell Perhaps I am missing something, but what stops the the prover from having two different values that can be written as $x_1 = g_1 ^ {s + n_1 \cdot q_2}$ and $x_2 = g_2 ^ {s + n_2 \cdot q_1}$, where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are arbitrary integers.  Then, the prover could set $z = r + e \cdot (s + n_1 \cdot q_2 + n_2 \cdot q_1) \mod q_1 \cdot q_2$.  This, as far as I can tell, would pass the test, even though the actually messages could be anything or have no real relationship to each other.  (Sorry for the post necro)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a paper describing how to do it efficiently, with some concrete sizes depending on the size of $a$ and $b$: https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1593, Fig. 1 (check table 1 for notation).
It uses the same ideas already suggested by Geoffroy and Yehuda, with the additional paradigm of Fiat-Shamir with aborts which results in a better concrete efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind performance too much, perhaps the following could work:

Observe that $G_1 \times G_2$ is a cyclic group of order $q_1q_2$, and that $(g_1,g_2)$ is a generator for this group.

The problem of equality of discrete logarithms as specified then reduces to showing that the logarithm of $(x_1,x_2)$ to the base $(g_1,g_2)$ is smaller than $\min\{q_1,q_2\}$.

I do not know what the state of the art is for range proofs for discrete logarithms. But the naive approach is to show that $s$ or $\min\{q_1,q_2\}-s-1$ can be written as a suitably small binary number. Which you can do as follows:

- Commit to the bits of the number by committing to $1$ or the generator (raised to $2^i$) using a homomorphic commitment scheme.
- Prove that each commitment is a bit commitment, using an "or"-proof.
- Add the commitments up.
- Open the commitment to the correct value.

There are a number of details I haven't worked out.

(If you can do significantly better than a range proof for discrete logarithms, then perhaps you have a better (but somewhat restricted) range proof for discrete logarithms...)

Answer (score 1):

This paper provides a solution that uses zk-SNARK:

https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1079