# Proving knowledge of a value and computation that uses it

Tags: protocol-design, zero-knowledge-proofs, protocol-analysis

Alice picks random points `P` and `Q` in a group where DLP w.r.t. a base point `G` is hard (I am thinking an elliptic curve, but it doesn't have to be). Alice doesn't know the DLP of those two points.

Alice sends `(P,Q)` to Bob.

Bob is to pick a random scalar `r`, and return `(r*P,r*Q)` to Alice, while keeping `r` secret.

Is there a way for Bob to prove to Alice that he knows that `r`, and that the pair of points that he sent her are what she is expecting, but without revealing `r`?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15758/23623) and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44744/23623) related Q&A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like your typical Schnorr identification protocol. Here $r$ is some secret value, which we could think of as having two public keys $r\cdot P$ and $r\cdot Q$. You'll probably want to assume that the DLPs wrt base $P$ and $Q$ are hard as well, as otherwise Alice could possible solve one of these two for $r$. Let's just assume the group has prime order $n$.

Now we could proceeds as follows (similar to the questions the @SEJPM referred to):

1. Bob chooses random $s\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
2. Bob sends $(s\cdot P, s\cdot Q)$ to Alice.
3. Alice chooses random $c\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
4. Bob computes $t = (s + cr)\bmod{n}$.
5. Bob sends $t$ to Alice.
6. Alice checks that $tP = (s\cdot P) + c(r\cdot P)$ and $tQ = (s\cdot Q) + c(r\cdot Q)$.

If the checks of Alice pass, she will believe that Bob knows the DLP of $r\cdot P$ and $r\cdot Q$. I haven't done a too thorough checking, but the properties of a sigma protocol seem to hold.

Moreover the secrets must both be equal to $(t-s)c^{-1}\bmod{n}$, so they are the same.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.